# Как сделать границы (прямоугольник столкновения) меньшим размером, чем спрайт в pygame

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

У меня есть класс игрока, отвечающий за главного персонажа. Также у меня есть листы спрайтов (idle, run, attack, take hit и т.д.). Но сам по себе спрайт во время атаки больше, чем спрайт бега, а спрайт бега больше спрайта во время бездействия. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при изменении спрайта прямоугольник столкновения (self.rect) оставался прежним, ведь если я анимации сменится, а прямоугольник останется тем же, то спрайты анимации будут обрезаны. А если увеличить прямоугольник, то границы столкновения тоже сместятся (этого мне не надо)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jack_oS У меня нет никаких  проблем, связанных с кодом, что показывать-то? Я просто спросил как реализовать данную модель.

Comment: Вы не знаете, как это сделать?